# Export an NFS mount via NFS

Tags: nfs, sles

I have a server "A" that has an NFS mount /FOO.

I setup an NFS server on server "A" to export the NFS mount /FOO.

I have other server: "B". But I cannot mount the /FOO from server "A" - probably because it was already an NFS mount.

I can export local dir on server "A", but not an NFS mount.

OS is SLES 11.

The question: how can I export an NFS mount via NFS to other servers? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most Linux OSes you cannot do this, this is by design the second server trying to export an NFS file-system would have multiple issues (permissions, file locking, etc.).

There was a time you could work around this with a bind mount but at the very least that is bad practice and highly NOT recommended. I believe doing it this was has also been removed.

Comment: are there alternatives in order to consolidate exported folders from various network disks, through a single node?