# How can I [nfs] share a folder that contains [nfs] shares from another computer (nfs is replaceable by other protocols)

Tags: nfs, cifs, sshfs, shared-folders

I have a number of network storage nodes, and a primary server that everyone connects too.
I would like to export shared folders from the storage nodes , so as to mount them on the primary server. Then the primary server can export on its own shared folders (some of which are simple forwards of the shared folders from the storage nodes).

The storage nodes are connected to the primary server through ethernet connections, as do the users. However, I want to avoid connections of the users directly to the individual storage nodes. Instead I want to tweak the ACLs in the primary server only, to effectively control access to all the shares.

I wanted to do that through "NFS" in both sides

```
storage nodes ---NFS---> primary srv ---NFS---> users
```

but I do not see the storage nodes' shares from user pc's. I [realised](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434097/29529) that this is by design, not a mis-configuration on my part.

I tested the following and it does work:

```
storage nodes ---NFS---> primary srv ---CIFS---> users
```

which is nice, but I wanted to avoid cifs in between gnu/linux only systems.

SSHFS also does not work

```
storage nodes ---NFS---> primary srv ---SSHFS---> users
```

At this point I have started losing faith in whether I can even achieve what I want.

Is there some other way? Note that I have kept the storage --> primary server link is always show through NFS because that would be my preferred choice, but if there is ANY way to consolidate the shared folders from the storage nodes, please do no hesitate to suggest them

Comment: You might look at my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315690/119298) for re-exporting cifs to nfs via an intermediary fuse fs, which I think I also tested for nfs->fuse->nfs. I'm not sure I would like to use this for other than read-only use on fairly static storage system. [fuse](https://github.com/fuse4x/fuse/blob/master/README.NFS) says use `noforget` and my notes say also `use_ino` or `readdir_ino`, but I don't remember why.

Comment: @meuh tried your solution with a read only mounted nfs that i wanted to share via nfs to other clients and it works.